# Isn't the 'r' letter making the regex pattern string literal?

Tags: python, regex

I had thought the 'r' prefix in the pattern is to make sure that anything in the pattern will be interpreted as string literal, so that I don't have to use escape, but in this case below, I still have to use '.' for literal match. So what's the purpose of the 'r' in the beginning of the regex?

```
    pattern = r'.'
    
    text = "this is. test"
    
    text = re.sub(pattern, ' ', text)
```

Comment: On my system, the value of test becomes `'             '`, because the regex character `.` matches anything. So `.` isn't being interpreted literally. Is that the intent?

Comment: The purpose of the "r" is to stop interpretation of backslash escapes.  What you need is `pattern = '\\.'` which can be written `pattern = r'\.`'.  A regex that allowed only string literals wouldn't be useful.

Comment: You are comparing apples with tractors. Character literal and regexp *meaning* of the char are two different things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `r` prefix stands for "raw."  It means that escape sequences inside a raw string will appear as literal.  Consider:

```py
print('Hello\b World')   # Hello World
print(r'Hello\b World')  # Hello\b World
```

In the first non raw string example, `\b` is interpreted as a control character (which doesn't get printed).  In the second example using a raw string, `\b` is a literal word boundary.

Another example would be comparing `'\1'` to `r'\1'`.  In the former, `'\1'` is a control character, while the latter is the first capture group.  Note that to represent the first capture group without using a raw string we can double up backslashes, i.e. use `'\\1'`.

Comment: In all situations, 'r' should be prefixed when writing regex? I saw others' code doing this way.

Comment: @marlon If you don't use raw strings, then you will have to do more backslash escaping.